# How to benefit from type-overloading when iterating without downcasting?

Tags: c#, oop, c#-4.0, refactoring

I've found some code that is a bit long in a method:

```
class Parent { }

class Son : Parent { }

class Daughter : Parent { }

class MainClass
{
    private void Iterate(IEnumerable<Parent> list)
    {
        foreach (Parent item in list) {
            if (item is Son) {
                ...SOME CODE...
            }
            else if (item is Daughter) {
                ...MORE CODE...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Because of this big if-else block, the method is quite large, and smells as bad design (OOP-wise).

I've tried to come up with something a bit more polymorphic, taking advantage of method-overloading via different type-paramaters, such as:

```
class MainClass
{
    private static void DoSomething (Son son)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Son");
    }

    private static void DoSomething (Daughter daughter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Daughter");
    }

    private static void DoSomething (Parent parent)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Parent");
    }

    private void Iterate(IEnumerable<Parent> list)
    {
        foreach (var item in list) {
            DoSomething (item);
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work because it always prints "Parent", so I guess I would need to downcast manually, which defeats the point a bit, and would not look elegant.

**One last point: if you are tempted to recommend me to put the implementation of `DoSomething` in the derived classes of Parent, that is not possible, because of dependency problems (the assembly where these 3 classes live cannot have dependencies on some things that the SOME CODE and MORE CODE is calling).**

So what would be the best approach to refactor this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this asides from the switch statement you've already identified (which definitely gets clunky with more than a couple of types involved).

First of all, if you aren't likely to add subtypes, but you *are* likely to add other things to do with the subtypes, you can use the [Visitor Pattern to mimic double dispatch](http://ericlippert.com/2015/05/04/wizards-and-warriors-part-three/).

```
class Parent
{
  public abstract void Accept(IChildVisitor visitor);
}

class Son : Parent
{
  public override void Accept(IChildVisitor visitor)
  {
    visitor.Visit(this);
  }
}

class Daughter : Parent
{
  public override void Accept(IChildVisitor visitor)
  {
    visitor.Visit(this);
  }
}

interface IChildVisitor
{
  Visit(Son son);
  Visit(Daughter daughter);
}

class SomeCodeChildVisitor : IChildVisitor
{
  public Visit(Son son)
  {
    ...SOME CODE...
  }
  public Visit(Daughter daughter)
  {
    ...SOME CODE...
  }
}

class MainClass
{
  private void Iterate(IEnumerable<Parent> list)
  {
    foreach (Parent item in list) {
        item.Accept(new SomeCodeChildVisitor());
    }
  }
}
```

You can also use a `Dictionary<Type,Action>`

```
class Parent { }

class Son : Parent { }

class Daughter : Parent { }

class MainClass
{
  // If you don't actually need a reference to the child
  private void IDictionary<Type, Action> map =
    new Dictionary<Type, Action>()
    {
      { typeof(Son), () => ...SOME CODE... }
      { typeof(Daughter), () => ...SOME CODE... }
    };

  // If you do need a reference to the child
  private void IDictionary<Type, Action<Parent>> otherMap =
    new Dictionary<Type, Action<Parent>>()
    {
      { typeof(Son), x => (Son)x. ...SOME CODE... }
      { typeof(Daughter), y => (Daughter)x. ...SOME CODE... }
    };      

  private void Iterate(IEnumerable<Parent> list)
  {
    foreach (Parent item in list) {
        // either
        map[item.GetType()]();

        // or
        otherMap[item.GetType()](item);
    }
  }
}
```

You can also use the `dynamic` keyword

```
class Parent { }

class Son : Parent { }

class Daughter : Parent { }

class MainClass
{
  private void Iterate(IEnumerable<Parent> list)
  {
    foreach (Parent item in list) {
        Visit((dynamic)item);
    }
  }

  private void Visit(Son son)
  {
    ...SOME CODE...
  }
  private void Visit(Daughter daughter)
  {
    ...SOME CODE...
  }
}
```

You can also just filter the types straight out of your collection with Linq (especially if you only care about some subtypes and not others, e.g. if you're iterating through a `Controls` collection and you only care about `Buttons`)

```
class Parent { }

class Son : Parent { }

class Daughter : Parent { }

class MainClass
{
  private void Iterate(IEnumerable<Parent> list)
  {
    foreach (Daughter daughter in list.OfType<Daughter>()) {
        ...SOME CODE...
    }
  }
}
```

In C# I generally recommend the dictionary approach, but any will do in a pinch.

Comment: Don't use pre tags for formatting code.  Just indent everything and you'll get nice code formatting.

Comment: @juharr: It didn't like the indents after the bullet points for some reason, so I just popped the tags in.

Comment: Then just don't use bullet points, they don't add anything useful.

Comment: I don't like to use the dynamic keyword, feels dirty, as if I was converting my C# language to Python...  The dictionary solution feels a bit weird (putting code in a dictionary initialization... and casting inside that code, mmm). So I tried to implement the visitor pattern in the code, and I found it to be too noisy, too much boilerplate code (the overriden methods all do the same in all derived classes), not to mention I would need to do an object allocation for each iteration, and I would need to have a new interface and method, visible in Parent, which doesn't really belong to that domain

Answer (score 0):

The best situation is to move DoSomething() method to the classes. If not possible, maybe you still can use conditionals to polymorphism, but with the decorator pattern. In this case you can

- Define an abstract class with an abstract method DoSomething(). Let's call it FamilyDecorator. It's a good idea to create a constructor which receives a Parent in his parameter, so you can save it as a protected variable (that means: visible to all of the derived classes).
- Declare one decorator for each class on your assembly: ParentDecorator, SonDecorator, DaughterDecorator. These three classes inherit from FamilyDecorator and must override the DoSomething() method.
- The trick is to create a method in the abstract class that returns one or another Decorator, based on type. That's the way you can separate which logic use on each case:

  ```
  abstract class FamilyDecorator
  {
    protected Domain.Parent _member;

    public abstract void DoSomething();

    internal FamilyDecorator(Domain.Parent member)
    {
      _member = member;
    }

    public static FamilyDecorator GetDecorator(Domain.Parent item)
    {
      if(item.GetType() == typeof(Domain.Parent))
      {
        return new ParentDecorator(item);
      }
      else if (item.GetType() == typeof(Domain.Son))
      {
        return new SonDecorator(item);
      }
      else if (item.GetType() == typeof(Domain.Daughter))
      {
        return new DaughterDecorator(item);
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
  class ParentDecorator : FamilyDecorator
  {
    internal ParentDecorator(Domain.Parent parent)
      : base(parent)
    {
    }

    public override void DoSomething()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("A parent");
    }
  }
  class SonDecorator : FamilyDecorator
  {
    internal SonDecorator(Domain.Parent son)
      : base(son)
    {
      this._member = son;
    }
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("A son");
    }
  }
  class DaughterDecorator : FamilyDecorator
  {
    internal DaughterDecorator(Domain.Parent daughter)
      : base(daughter)
    {

    }
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("A daughter");
    }
  }
  ```

Then, in your Main class:

```
    foreach (Parent item in list)
    {
      var decorator = FamilyDecorator.GetDecorator(item);
      decorator.DoSomething();
    }
```

This solution keeps the code very clean and takes advantage of polymorphism.

**Edit**

> I don't think I like this solution because you're basically moving the
>   type checking from the foreach loop to the GetDecorator() method.
>   Polymorphism should allow you to do this without type checking
>   manually.

There is another solution, based on the same idea: to use reflection for the object construction.

In this case:

- Instead of an abstract class you define an Interface that declares the DoSomething() method.
- Now each decorator inherits from their corresponding class (Parent - ParentDecorator, Son - SonDecorator, etc.)
- You need to change the constructors in the Decorator classes. They need to be public if you want to use reflection.
- Finally, the GetDecorator() method just search for the derived class in the assembly. If found, it returns the decorator.

  ```
  namespace FamilyNamespace
  {
    interface IFamily
    {
      void DoSomething();
    }

    class ParentDecorator : Domain.Parent, IFamily
    {
      private Domain.Parent _member;

      public ParentDecorator(Domain.Parent parent)
      {
        this._member = parent;
      }

      public void DoSomething()
      {
        Console.WriteLine("A parent");
      }
    }

    class SonDecorator : Domain.Son, IFamily
    {
      private Domain.Parent _member;

      public SonDecorator(Domain.Parent son)
      {
        this._member = son;
      }
      public void DoSomething()
      {
        Console.WriteLine("A son");
      }
    }
    class DaughterDecorator : Domain.Daughter, IFamily
    {
      private Domain.Parent _member;

      public DaughterDecorator(Domain.Parent daughter)
      {
        this._member = daughter;
      }
      public void DoSomething()
      {
        Console.WriteLine("A daughter");
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Then in your Main class:

```
    static FamilyNamespace.IFamily GetDecorator(Domain.Parent item)
    {
      var baseType = item.GetType();

      var derivedType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(m => m != baseType && baseType.IsAssignableFrom(m));
      if (derivedType.Any())
      {
        return (FamilyNamespace.IFamily)Activator.CreateInstance(derivedType.First(), new object[] { item });
      }
      return null;
    }
```

... and the Main method:

```
    foreach (Domain.Parent item in list)
    {
      var decorator = (FamilyNamespace.IFamily)GetDecorator(item);
      decorator.DoSomething();
    }
```

Greetings

Comment: I don't think I like this solution because you're basically moving the type checking from the foreach loop to the GetDecorator() method. Polymorphism should allow you to do this without type checking manually.